# Can multiplayer games mix softcore/hardcore mode?

Tags: starbound

Is it possible for two players to play together, one in softcore and one in permadeath mode? In that case, is there any specific handling for pvp? Assumed that we are in a pvp server, players are allowed to fight in any case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I read this answer

> It is possible to cheat in every game because you can modify data in
>   the computer memory, secu preventions can mitigate the hacks but will
>   never stops cheats, VAC for example bans known exploits but if you are
>   enough good to find a hack yourself and exploit it privately, you can
>   hack for life without being caught
>
> Yet anyway Starbound is nude of any security prevention so yes it is
>   easy to cheat and yes everywhere, plus the mods are not enough
>   restricted, most mods outta there are just shebangs cheat machines
>
> pvp is just about hitting turning on /pvp
>
> softcore, hardcore, permadeath plays on the same server
>
> Actually there is bugs and you can be killed without even being in pvp
>   mode /pvp, trolls uses grenade launchers etc.. etc..
>
> What to say , else, alpha game ^^

on SB forum I can say that being this game in alpha softcore, hardcore and perma players are on the same server.
Pvp is just a flag on/off for every server but players could exploit bugs for trolling others in any case. So beware the internet!